# I want to adjust the graph area in ggplot2

Tags: r, networking, ggplot2

I made the following graph using the geomnet package and ggplot2. Then exported it to a pdf. But the graph by itself seems to be larger than the graphing area. it seems to be framed in a small square, as you can see in this picture:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqnIZ.png)

[image]

I don't know how to change the size of the square that's framing my graph so that the net nodes will be shown fully in my pdf. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code i'm using, and a data example:

```
red_list<-data_frame(From=c("A","B","C","D","D"),To=c("C","C","D","Z","A"))

red_list%>%ggplot(aes(from_id=From,to_id=To))+
geom_net(layout.alg = "circle", labelon = TRUE,
size = 12, directed = TRUE, fontsize=2, vjust = 0.5, labelcolour = "grey80",
arrowsize = 1.5, linewidth = 0.5, arrowgap = 0.05, col="darkred",
selfloops = F, ecolour = "grey40") + 
theme_net() +
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5),
plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=.5))+
ggtitle(label=paste("Figura",i,sep=" "),subtitle = paste("Interacciones entre los sectores de",names(red_list)[i],by=" ")))
```

Comment: Are you using `ggsave` or the export button in rstudio? `ggsave` is generally better for saving figures

Comment: i'm using rmarkdown to create a pdf document. Simply printing the graph.

Comment: You should set `fig.width=???, fig.height=???` in your Rmarkdown code chunk

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well it will work with graphs, but I uselly play with `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(...,...), ylim = c(...,...)` to adjust the plotting area.